# QGIS 3.6 picture in ui form (Qt5 Designer)

Tags: qgis-3, qt-designer

I'm facing trouble with display a picture in a ui form based on a field (path).
With the autogenerate form it works but when I try with a personalized form I cannot see the picture.
I tried with a Qlabel and QWebView in Qt Designer and in QGIS layer property I put the field as Attachment but without success.

I know that I can make a little python script to achieve this but I would like to store the ui in a db.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: A similar issue was solved (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/146900/143501) in this thread (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144427/how-to-display-a-picture-in-qgis-custom-form)

Comment: Yes I've already read this thread, but it was solved by a python script, and want to avoid to use python because the user will just connect to a database when I can store the ui form. In that case the user doesn't need a python plugin or script.
By the way I succeeded in that with the older 2.18 version.

Comment: You have the solution here without using python https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/162874/49538

Comment: This doesn't work with QGIS 3.6

Comment: Same in here. I designed quite a lot of complex custom forms to manage pictures and I don't want to have to rebuild everything at every new version… It worked right out-of-the-box with 2.18 and not anymore with version 3…

Answer (score 2):

It seems possible by tricking QGIS and Qt Creator.

This is how I proceeded.

In QtCreator, you create a new QTextBrowser widget. As usual, you give it the name of the QGIS source field. You need to right click on the new widget and select "Promote In…" and enable both options "QtWebView/QtWebKit" and "QgsExternalResourceWidget" if they are not.

[image]

In QGIS now, you select your custom form.
The source field has to be set as a Text source. You have to enable HTML rendering as well.

[image]

The data has to be input as HTML inside the field.
So you can create for example a field in which you will store the path of your picture and then create a calculation field rendering HTML as follow:

```
'<img src="' || "Photo" || '">'
```

[image]

That's all what you have to do.
That will let you create more beautiful forms than the ones in QGIS.
It's even more simple than before.

Answer (score -2):

you can use tips tool  in **qgis** and write with html code for insert any file and even open file out of **qgis**

Comment: That means to have access to the user's QGIS desktop... Want a very simple solution, just opening the form from the database. It was possible with 2.18 version.