# How to display an image in a UI custom form created with QtDesigner in QGIS 3.28

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qt-designer

I created a custom form with QtDesigner. For the image in the form I used a QLabel and added the path of the picture to the "pixmap" attribute. The path is

> C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Formulare\Baum_grün.png

The object name of the lable is called "Bild"

[image]

In the attribute table of the Layer I have a column called "Bild" with the path of the picture.

[image]

In the layer properties I set the path to the image as well.
When I use a automatic created form I can display the image:

[image]

However, when I choose my prepared .ui Form I can't display the image:

[image]

Is it possible to display the image I created in my .ui form? And if yes where is my mistake? I use QGIS 3.28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pixmap` attribute of <kbd>QLabel</kbd> won't let you refer to a dynamic field value via QtDesigner, only let you load a static image from an absolute file path.

I think using <kbd>QLabel</kbd> itself to dynamically display images was an old method used in QGIS 2.x with the deprecated `Photo` QGIS widget type.

---

#### QgsExternalResourceWidget

From 3.x it appears the direct alternative is to use<kbd>QgsExternalResourceWidget</kbd> ([ref github issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30833#issuecomment-514062957)) instead, along with the `Attachment` QGIS widget type.

Instructions:

- In QGIS, set up the field to use the `Attachment` widget:

  - Go to <kbd>Layer Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Attribute Form</kbd>, set the `Bild` widget type to `Attachment`
  - Store path as = Relative to Project Path
  - Integrated Document Viewer = Image
  - Display Resource Path = disabled, if you only want to see the image and no file path, as in your example
- In QtDesigner, add a <kbd>QgsExternalResourceWidget</kbd> to your form and name it `Bild` (`objectName` property).

  - Some of the other properties (e.g. `relativeStorage`, `fileWidgetVisible`) seem to be overridden by the QGIS widget settings described above so may not be worth setting up here.

Result:

[image]

---

#### QTextBrowser + HTML

Alternatively, you can try a <kbd>QWidget</kbd> container then adding a <kbd>TextBrowser</kbd> widget inside it, alongside the QGIS `Text Edit` widget (enable Multiline and HTML) as explained in [this answer for QGIS 3.6](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367716/98784).

However, a couple of drawbacks:

- Instead of the `Bild` field as-is, as the link explains, you would need to use a Virtual Field that adds the `<img>` tags to the field value, and in your case, also generating the full file path, so an expression like:

  ```
  '<img src="' || @project_folder || '\\' || "Bild" || '">'
  ```

  And name the <kbd>QTextBrowser</kbd> widget after the Virtual Field
- The result will not auto resize the image by default or in any easy way, I think you need to specify it in the Virtual Field HTML or maybe fiddle around with the <kbd>QWidget</kbd> / <kbd>QTextBrowser</kbd> properties. By default it would look something like the below.

  [image]

Comment: Wonderful! the "QgsExternalResourceWidget" solution works perfectly for me. Thank you very much